# How to solve this querying?

Tags: sql, reporting-services

i've a problem with a SSRS report and query in Sql Server 2008 that, in my opinion, is (easy) solvable in excel  ... but, not in Sql !
Follow what i need:

My table:

Start amount X: 1.000.000

```
      Month    Value               AmountX
      1        1 000         (AmountX - Value)       = 999 000
      2          500         (Prev. AmountX - Value) = 998 500
      3          800         (Prev. AmountX - Value) = 997 700 
      .....
      .....
```

Comment: Extremely vague, please tell us more.

Comment: You need to keep a running balance? How do you get the start value `1,000,000`?

Comment: Yes, i've a starting value getted from a table...

Comment: So, you basically want a running total. What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: in sql server you can do this with a cursor

Comment: @Lamak SSRS *strongly* implies that it's SQL Server...

Comment: @bluefeet In SQL Server you can do it **without** a `CURSOR`, too.. Ugh

Comment: @Yuck agreed, just making a suggestion

Comment: @Yuck - Yes, but for this kind of query, what version of SQL Server is very important

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out `RunningValue()`, you would use this as a function in your SSRS report

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159136(v=sql.100).aspx

```
=RunningValue(Fields!Value.Value, Sum, Nothing)
```